# How to set Vagrants VM displayname in vmware_workstation

Tags: vagrant, vmware-workstation

I am trying to set the VM displayname in vmware via Vagrant:

Here is my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "precise64"   config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64_vmware.box"


  config.vm.provider :vmware_workstation do |vb|
    vb.name = "my_crazy_vm_name_rulezz"
  end

end
```

But the vmware Machine name still defaults to "vm: default"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each provider is configured completely differently. What you're doing there is trying to use the VirtualBox's configuration `.name` to set something in VMWare, where there is no such "name" attribute. In VMWare there are only two things you can set (as far as I know), which are:

```
.gui = true/false     # Enables/disables display of the VMWare GUI when you start this VM
.vmx['key'] = 'value' # Sets a value in the .vmx file for this VM
```

The .vmx configuration is what you're looking for, since it has a handy 'displayname' key. SO... here's the configuration you're looking for

```
config.vm.provider :vmware_workstation do |v|
    v.vmx['displayname'] = 'My Custom VM Name'
end
```

You can find other values you can configure this way by looking at the .vmx file for your VM in a text editor. This file can be found at: `.vagrant/machines/default/vmware_workstation/{some_big_id}/{something}.vmx`